# How to get CSRF token on authorization request with OWASP ZAP in bruteforce mode

Tags: csrf, owasp, zap

I am a new in OWASP ZAP, so I need your help.

I have vulnerability site - DVWA. I am trying to work on token (CSRF) in bruteforce.

When page load I have HTML form with login, password and user-token. Third field are filled by dynamic token (CSRF).

I need to use bruteforce with CSRF token.

1) Receive user_token from loaded page 2) Send form through Fuzzer

As I understand, I need to create script for receiving user_token from loaded page and then run Attak -> Fuzz on authorization link, then select user_token value and add playload script that will fill it on each request.

But I can't find any information in Internet how to create this script, please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Response in google group.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/zaproxy-users/1OyLNAYVBic

Thanks all.